# YouTube iFrame Player API failed to execute postMessage on DOMWindow

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am trying to load youtube into my web page using **`YouTube iFrame Player API`**, and getting following error while loading:

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://developer-sandbox.com').
```

both origin and target are `https`, there are few **SO** post which resolves the issue by keeping origin & target url to https. In this case both are same.

Following is the JS code I am used to load the player dynamically:

```
showVideoPreview: function(youtube_id){
        var meThis = this;
        var player = new YT.Player('shoppable-video-container', {
            height  : '315',
            width   : '560',
            videoId : youtube_id,
            events  : {
                'onReady'       : meThis.onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange' : meThis.onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }
```

[image: youtube iframe api video loading error view]

Comment: In my case it is because jQuery was load in the `<head>` section. Move it to `<body>` section at below but before `<script src='https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script>` works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `loadVideoById`

> This function loads and plays the specified video.
>
> - The required **`videoId`** parameter specifies the YouTube Video ID of the video to be played. In the YouTube Data API, a **`video`** resource's [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#id) property specifies the ID.
> - The optional **`startSeconds`** parameter accepts a float/integer. If it is specified, then the video will start from the closest keyframe to the specified time.
> - The optional **`endSeconds`** parameter accepts a float/integer. If it is specified, then the video will stop playing at the specified time.
> - The optional **`suggestedQuality`** parameter specifies the suggested playback quality for the video. Please see the definition of the [**`setPlaybackQuality`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#setPlaybackQuality) function for more information about playback quality.

Here is a snippet to help you

JS

```
function searchVideo(){
var vID = document.getElementById("vidID").value
player.loadVideoById(vID, 0, "default");

}
```

HTML

```
Search by Video ID: <input type="text" id="vidID" name="vidID"><button onclick="searchVideo()">Search</button>
```